# Select neuron based on weights and bias

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

In a dense layer with 2048 neurons where each and every neuron is connected with previous layer output we have:

```
y = w1*x1 + w2*x2 + .......... + w128*x128
```

so total (128*2048) = 262144 parameters with 2048 bias vectors totally 264192 (262144 + 2048) parameters.

I need to select the neuron (or first x neurons) out of 2048 with the highest scores. How should I base my decision?

UPDATE:
I got the above shape: 128 * 2048 connections and 2048 biases. I need to find the most influential neuron out of the 2048. I suppose I should take into consideration all 128 weights and the bias for every neuron, but I am not sure how I should calculate the max. Sum of all weights? And how about the bias?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result tensor has shape `res.shape = [batch_size, 2048]`:

- if you want the neuron with the highest output:

```
np.argmax(res, axis=-1)
```

- if you want top K neurons:

```
np.argpartition(res, -K, axis=-1)[:,-K:]
```

Comment: I need the neuron with the highest weight, not thw highest activation. My question is should I consider the weights only or the bias as well?

Comment: I apologize. Would you then share with me your definition of 'highest score'/'highest weight'? Because weights are usually in the form of a matrix, biases are usually represented as a vector.

Comment: I got the above shape: 128 * 2048 connections and 2048 biases. I need to find the most influential neuron out of the 2048. I suppose I should take into consideration all 128 weights and the bias for every neuron, but I am not sure how I should calculate the max. Sum of all weights? And how about the bias?